# Global variable in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm writing c++ project, which contains several classes. I created .h file named Position.h, with one array and one function:

```
class Position
{
public:
    Coord positions[25];

public:
    void setPos(int index, double x, double y)
    {
        positions[index].x = x;
        positions[index].y = y;
    }
};
```

I want to set values in this array from another classes, so every class in this project will see the same values.
I included "Position.h" in other classes, but i can't access the "positions" array.

Anyone can help me plz??

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Insert obligitory "globals suck" comment here.

Comment: As an aside you should make your positions member private, and provide a `Coord getPosition(int index)` function. I would also change the `setPos` function to void `setPos(int index, Coord pos)`. And as Luchian Grigore said in his answer, a `vector` would make this class a lot more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chnage the statement :

```
Coord positions[25];
```

to

```
static Coord positions[25];
```

also change `void setPos`
to

```
static void setPos
```

while accesing the array ,access it as:

```
Position::positions[any value]
```

But before accessing the array,make sure you call the function `setPos`

Comment: Thanx, I used it and i think it works, but now i added "getPos(int index)" which returns double, and there is an error while i write "double x = Position::getPos(5)".... maybe in getters it is different..?

Comment: @kande: No, it's the same. But instead of changing everything to `static`, take one step back. How many `Position`s are there in your program, and how many `Position::positions` ?

Comment: in one class i have a method that sets the values and another class has method that gets the values. for set i used: `Position::setPos(index, x,y)`, and for get i used `Position::getPos(index)` which returns Coord. it doesn't work. i get an error: "Undefined reference to Position::positions"

Answer (score 1):

`positions` is a member variable associated with a class instance, and therefore not a global. You can make it similar to a global by making it `static`. Doing so, it will become a class-scoped variable, and not bound to an instance.

You will need to define it in a single implementation file.

An even better alternative would be having an `std::vector<Coord>`.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but if i'll make the array "static" i won't be able to change it?

Comment: @kande you're confusing `static` with `const`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, you can make the members `static`.

You can also create an instance of the `Position` class as a global variable, and use that:

```
Position globalPosition;

void function_using_position()
{
    globalPosition.setPos(0, 1, 2);
}

int main()
{
    function_using_position();
}
```

Or make it a local variable, and pass it around as a reference:

```
void function_using_position(Position &position)
{
    position.setPos(0, 1, 2);
}

int main()
{
    Position localPosition;

    function_using_position(localPosition);
}
```

Comment: +1 on this. `Position` seems like a fairly re-usable class, so you probably don't want to cripple its usefulness by making it `static`. By having a globally accessible instance of this class you get the best of both worlds.